# Authentication against a web service without involving Grails domains

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have legacy database for my app and I have to add app to common sign in  where the user table related to sign in is not accessible, but I have access to app which gives JSON output for login authentication.

For this I'm trying to use spring security plugin but I am not able to figure out the entry point of url and how to redirect input from login page to url.

Comment: Try go ogling grails spring security custom authentication provider here is an example http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2010/01/15/hacking-custom-authentication-providers-with-grails-spring-security.html

Comment: Thank you vahid ,but I have tried following that article gives me compilation errors as ...unable to resolve class AuthenticationProvider
unable to resolve class Authentication
And so on…I refreshed dependency but still same exceptions..

Comment: How about http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/1.5.1/docs/index.html

Comment: I am not able to import grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.credentials and also not able to configure grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.usernamePropertyName username  these parameters in config 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName password

Comment: What version of grails are you using ? please refer to http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/ mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'

Comment: I'm using grails 2.4.4..It will be helpful if you provide link to any working example or so....thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all above answers helped me alot along with objectpartners.com  to customize spring security plugin
https://objectpartners.com/2013/07/11/custom-authentication-with-the-grails-spring-security-core-plugin/
https://github.com/JacobASeverson/smart-notes